# Can I collect mmap read/write statistics?

Tags: c++, mmap

I am experimenting in using `mmap` to optimize certain parts of a program. In the end, I'd like to have statistics about how much was read and written to disk by a particular `mmap` call. Is there any way to get I/O statistics for this? (I'm using C++, and I'd like this to work cross-platform.)

Comment: This should go under the normal io statistics for your process. mmap() and friends are lazy functions, they may not actually pull any pages in until your program actually touches them.

Comment: `mmap` is inherently non-portable, it only works on the linux kernel.

Comment: @oakad That's why I'm curious about actual usage stats. Obviously I can bookkeep everything in the app and try to subtract to get I/O for a single mmap, but this doesn't work if I have two.

Comment: @randomusername `mmap` works with [POSIX-compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) Unix, which is sufficiently cross-platform for my purposes. (Mac + linux flavors)

Comment: Hmmm... This is a little tricky as the OS can also pull pages away from you.  You can get some of these statistics in terms of page faults via `getrusage` (ru_majflt).  But, that'll be all faults, not just faults due to your `mmap` areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer is "no". Different operating systems operate `mmap` and its related system calls in different ways and there is no defined interface for querying such statistics at such a fine-grained level.